# imagecreatefrompng not works on server

Tags: php, centos, gd, libpng

`imagecreatefrompng` works fine in my localhost but when I upload my code in server it doesn't work. I try to know where is the error and I get `False` when var_dump `imagecreatefrompng` in the server but in localhost return `True`

The main error is:

> imagepng(): gd-png error: cannot allocate `libpng` main struct

My code:

```
<?php
$final_w = 600;
$final_h = 400;

$resize_width = min($final_h,$final_w);
$resize_height = min($final_h,$final_w);

$padding = (max($final_h,$final_w) - min($final_h,$final_w))/2;


header('Content-Type: image/png');
$image = imagecreate($final_w,$final_h);
$white = imagecolorallocatealpha( $image, 255, 255, 255 , 0 );

imagealphablending($image,true);

$image_2 = imagecreatefrompng('logo.png');
$image_3 = imagescale($image_2,$resize_width,$resize_height);

if ($final_w > $final_h) {
    $new = imagecopy($image, $image_3, $padding, 0, 0, 0, $resize_width, $resize_height);
} else
{
    $new = imagecopy($image, $image_3, 0, $padding, 0, 0, $resize_width, $resize_height);
}
imagepng($image);
```

### Localhost xampp config:

- PHP Version 7.2.5
- libPNG Version   1.6.34

### Server config:

- CentoOS
- PHP Version 7.2.12
- libPNG Version   1.5.13

Comment: check if this post helps you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31844401/gd-png-cannot-allocate-image-data

Comment: @GiacomoM I checked the post.....in phpInfo() gd writes "GD Version bundled (2.1.0 compatible)" but in my CentoOS server  in gdlib root is "usr/lib64/libgd.so.2.0.0"