# find out AF_UNIX + SOCK_SEQPACKET maximum message size

Tags: c, linux, sockets, unix

I wonder if there is any possibility to find out the max length of `SEQPACKET` except experimental (a-la `for( i=0; i<100...00; i++ ) send( ... );`).

And, the second question:

If I received `errno == EMSGSIZE` trying to send `AF_UNIX` `SEQPACKET`, is it guaranteed that it's because of max message size, or could there be some other reasons?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the max size of AF_UNIX datagram message that can be sent in linux?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4729315/what-is-the-max-size-of-af-unix-datagram-message-that-can-be-sent-in-linux)

Comment: Nope, that question is like "Is the max size actually 130688? If not can this be changed without recompiling the kernel?". But I need to find max size inside C program, I don't need to change it's value and I don't want to hardcode magic numbers like 130688 into the program.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Limit comes from variable `sysctl_wmem_default`. 
It is viewable in the proc filesystem: `/proc/sys/net/core/wmem_max`

Different Linux versions may have different implementation in this point. 
But there is this kind of code for UNIX domain sockets:

```
sk->sk_sndbuf = sysctl_wmem_default;
```

and

```
err = -EMSGSIZE;
if (len > sk->sk_sndbuf - 32)
    goto out;
```

So the actual limit is: **value of /proc/sys/net/core/wmem_max minus 32**.
I don't know how much this magic number changes between version.
Value of /proc/sys/net/core/wmem_max seems to vary depending of available ram pages.

In my linux box the value is 105472. And maximum datagram size (when using AF_UNIX and SOCK_DGRAM) is 105440. If I try to send message with size 105441, it will fail with EMSGSIZE.

Comment: My value is 212992 (= 52 * 4096).

Comment: The **minus 32** is probably to allow for the packet header.

Answer (score 0):

Just after you opened the socket, you can check with the following code:

```
int s = socket(AF_UNIX, SOCK_DGRAM, 0); // or SOCK_SEQPACKET
int dgram_max_size = 0;
socklen_t optlen = sizeof(dgram_max_size);
int r = getsockopt(s, SOL_SOCKET, SO_SNDBUF, &dgram_max_size, &optlen);
if(r != 0) {
    printf("error: can't retrieve socket max. size\n");
    exit(1);
}
```

For any socket, it has to be done before you send data to make sure that the size is the maximum. For datagram sockets, it is likely to work any time. For stream-base sockets, the buffer probably shrinks as you write to it and grows as the data gets sent.

**Note:** As mentioned by SKi, the size may be off by a *few bytes*. The 32 is probably the packet header. So your packet data is likely limited to `dgram_max_size - 32`.