# allocate a memory chunk at a specified address in Linux kernel

Tags: linux, memory, memory-management, linux-kernel

Is there a way in the Linux kernel to allocate a chunk of memory and specify that it needs to be at a specified virtual address?

I realize this may not always be possible, as that chunk of memory may not be available. But if that chunk happens to be available, is there a way for me to claim it?

I am asking this because I want to allocate a small chunk of memory at first, and if needed, increase its size without having to allocate another larger chunk of memory and copy everything over.

Edit:

As someone pointed one, at the user space, realloc() does exactly what I need. But is there an equivalent in kernel space?

Comment: Why would you want to do this?

Comment: Why not just reserve a chunk of address space that's larger than you will ever need?

Answer (score 1):

See [man `mremap()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mremap.2.html) for the mechanism that `realloc()` uses.  The mechanisms to implement this are in the kernel.  See [mremap.c](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/mm/mremap.c).  `mremap()` attempts to setup adjacent memory for user space so that a range maybe grown.  It may not apply well to kernel space.

You can request a region of virtual address space and also request it at [a specific address](https://www.kernel.org/doc/htmldocs/kernel-api/API-vmap.html).  See [`vmap()`](http://lwn.net/Articles/304188/) at LWN.  All that remains is to assign some physical pages to this virtual addresses.

`kmalloc()` works at the page level and then provides binning within pages (via SLAB, SLUB, etc). See [kmalloc size allocation‌](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12568379/kmalloc-size-allocation)​. In your case, you can not share the page so others can use it. If you grow the region and someone else uses it, then you have to move the memory.

See [`do_krealloc()`](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/mm/util.c#L110) for the moving. If your total size is small, then you can use `krealloc()`. If they are large (>16k), then you should be using `vmap()` or use the alternate interface of `vfs_writev()` instead of `vfs_write()`.  Note that even sizes of 16k may fail as system memory gets fragmented.  This is why people generally use only a page as it can never get fragmented.

Comment: Because later I need to pass this chunk of memory to vfs_write, which requires virtually continuous memory. I guess I could also apply for non-continuous memory chunks, and use vfs_writev(), but this way seems easier

Comment: Also, seems like vmap works at page level, is there something which works at byte level? Thanks!

Comment: realloc() works at byte level. I am thinking if there is something keep track of the memory being allocated on top of the page mapping, like the circular list libc maintains for malloc(), then it's possible to implement it. And since kernel has kmalloc(), I am hoping it has similar mechanism.

Comment: It sounds like you want a `vmrealloc()`, but I dont' believe this exists.