# Monitoring and settings of transfers using the Linux AF_UNIX?

Tags: linux, networking, kernel, datagram

I'm trying to setup a robust AF_UNIX data transfer.

So I make this test (on a Ubuntu 20.04):
I generate logs :

```
for a in  `seq 1 1000000`; do echo $a | logger; echo $a  ; done
```

I check my log file :

```
tail -f /var/log/syslog | less
```

I can see my logs logged by rsyslog in this file.

I stop rsyslog :

```
systemctl stop syslog.socket
```

No logs arrived anymore in /var/log/syslog as expected.

But when I restart rsyslog :

```
systemctl start syslog.socket
```

I can see that the logs arrvie again but most of the one created during the rsyslog outage are missing.

I tired to increase the max_dgram_qlen

```
echo 5000000 > /proc/sys/net/unix/max_dgram_qlen
```

but it doesn't change anything.

I read on this post [What is the max size of AF_UNIX datagram message in Linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4729315/what-is-the-max-size-of-af-unix-datagram-message-in-linux) that I can monitor the socket using:

```
ss -ax | grep log
```

but the counters looked to be at zero all the time whether rsyslog is started or not.

What I trying to do :

- increase the buffer to be able to have at least 500MB or 500,000 messages in queue
- be able to monitor the size of the queue : size or queue length
- if possible logging in dmesg when messages are dropped.

Comment: What is `logger`?

Comment: @Shawn logger is a basic unix command to enter a message into the system log (without argument, it connects to /dev/log and use sendmsg tu send its stdin on it)